# incorrect program scaling on screen makes it look blurry - fix?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, installation, flags, dpi

Compiled program (VB NET) looks blurry on screen, apparently because the dpi scaling is done by the OS and not the application.

When I change the desktop shortcut's Properties - Compatibility - Change high DPI settings to "Override high DPI scaling behavior" so the Application has control, AND start the program from that shortcut, then it does look sharp and nice.

[desktop shortcut settings manually changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DH8cr.jpg)

Question: how to achieve the same effect at the level of compiler/installer? I have control over both but don't know what to change.

Design environment: Visual Basic 2010 Express (yes, I know! But it does work fine for my purposes, so ain't broken - don't fix it here.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modify the application's `app.manifest` (or `app.config`, depending on the .Net Framework in use and the target System) to enable DPI Awareness. See this: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103). If you don't, your application may be subject to virtualization. The blurred appearance is just the more immediate, visual, consequence. Side note, `Visual Basic 2010` is very old. .Net Core 3.0 is coming. That will change something.

Comment: @Jimi I have added the following to my app.manifest:

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
      <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <windowsSettings>
          <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
        </windowsSettings>      
    </application>
  </compatibility>

Is it going to do the same as your linked post suggestion? The syntax is surely different...

Comment: @Jimi ...and I got it from [link](https://www.sgrottel.de/?p=1581&lang=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have researched the issue further and did a lot of tests.

The solution: set all Forms to AutoScale=Font

Apparently, Font knows the screen DPI resolution as well, so setting AutoScale to Font solves all the issues automatically.